# Telerik Silverlight PadPane Z-Order issue in RadDocking control

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I have created a usercontrol that contains a RadDocking control, with several panes, but they seem to lose their "z-order" when panes are closed.

For example, if I add 3 panes (pane1,pane2,pane3) to a panegroup in the following order: pane1, pane2, pane3.

I close pane 3, and pane 1 becomes the active pane instead of pane 2 - it is as if it goes back to the 1st item in the pane group

Any ideas?

Here is the XAML:

```
<telerik:RadDocking>
    <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                    <telerik:RadPane x:Name="pane1" Title="pane1">
            <TextBlock Text = "pane1" />
            </telerik:RadPane>

                    <telerik:RadDocumentPane x:Name="pane1" Title="pane2">
            <TextBlock Text = "pane2" />
            </telerik:RadDocumentPane>


                    <telerik:RadPane x:Name="pane3" Title="pane3">
            <TextBlock Text = "pane3" />
            </telerik:RadPane>
        </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
 <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
</telerik:RadDocking>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from Telerik:

this is a know issue that was fixed in our Q3 2012 SP1 release of RadControls. All you need to do is download that release or any internal build after it.